# Access a mustache template that was loaded in the html head tag?

Tags: javascript, mustache

Is there a way to access the contents of a mustache template file that is loaded via the HTML `<head>` via javascript?

```
<link rel="template" href="templates/address.mustache" type="text/html" />
```

or

```
<script src="templates/address_field.mustache" type="text/html" charset="utf-8" id="address_template"></script>
```

I've had success loading them through ajax and through a `<script>` tag in the body, but I'm not sure how to get the file source when loaded as a separate file through the head.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to use a selector that will get the contents of that html.

With jQuery it is as simple as:

```
var tmpl=$.trim($('#address_template').val()); //trim the white spaces in the template
Mustache.to_html(tmpl,json);
```

Comment: I upvoted you (and it's too late to fix) but the answer you've given doesn't work - .val() won't evaluate external files.

Answer (score 0):

you need to get method to catch template value external template: below codes only works inside of the html page:

```
var tmpl=$.trim($('#address_template').val()); //trim the white spaces in the template
```

Mustache.to_html(tmpl,json);

you need below codes:  "**$.get('template.html'**,"   is your answer trick. you should load your template firstly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

### Titles

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.getJSON('/data/speakers.json', function(data) {
            //var template = $('#speakers-template').html();

           // console.log(template);
           // var info = Mustache.render(template, data);
           // $('#talktitles').html(info);
```

$.get('template.html', function(template, textStatus, jqXhr) {
            var info =Mustache.render($(template).filter('#speakers-template').html(), data);
            $('#talktitles').html(info);
        });

```
        });
    });
</script>
```